All network connection options have vanished and booting into Emergency Mode - Ubuntu 24.04
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 on a 2011 Mac Mini and up until today haven't had any problems.
I tried to set a Static IP address through the "Network" GUI, but all my Network options disappeared after a reboot.
I tried sudo apt-get -y install network-manager-gnome and this confirmed that I had the latest version.
I then confirmed via sudo systemctl status NetworkManager that the Network Manager is up to date, installed and running but if I open Network within System Settings I only have the option of VPN or Proxy even though the device has an ethernet cable connected.

Wifi shows available networks but if I select one it does nothing but take me back to the Network GUI.
I'd appreciate any ideas...
EDIT
After rebooting the machine again it started up in Emergency Mode and reviewing the journalctl file I can see errors like /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan failed with exit status 1. which I assume is related.
